# Nuget issue Detected Package downgrade: Microsoft.Maui.Controls from 8.0.6 to 8.0.3

Tags: nuget, maui

I haven't had nuget issues for a very long time(VS2010), but I've been fighting these again over the past 1/2 year.  This time, I cannot seem to get by it.

This is a .net maui program targeting .net 8.

I can update Microsoft.Maui.Controls from 8.0.3 to 8.0.6 OR I can update Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility from 8.0.3 to 8.0.6, but NOT both at the same time.

The second one will get an error like this:

Error   NU1605  Warning As Error: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Maui.Controls from 8.0.6 to 8.0.3. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
MyApp -> Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility 8.0.6 -> Microsoft.Maui.Controls (>= 8.0.6)
MyApp -> Microsoft.Maui.Controls (>= 8.0.3)    MyApp

If I downgrade that one, I can install the other one but then I get the error message on the other one the same as above,but referring to the other package.

My project file has this after upgrading Microsoft.Maui.Controls to 8.0.6:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.6" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Anyone have an idea how to get around this?

Comment: That error message *looks* like one you've get if you had Microsoft.Maui.Controls version 8.0.3 in your project file. The snippet of your project file you've shown doesn't refer to Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility at all. Please could you post enough of the project file for us to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Do you actually need Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility? Do you know that? Can't you just remove it? Else you should be able to move them both to 8.0.6 without any issues. Possibly there is some other reference to 8.0.3 that might trigger this message.

Comment: Sometimes I don't see the tree in the forest. Thanks, you are correct; that project is not needed.

Comment: Except it won't let it go.  I didn't install that, I just assumed it was installed with the controls package.  Now I get to figure out why it's not letting it go to uninstall.

Comment: @Jon that is correct, there is no reference in the project file for that project which is also causing the issue removing it from my app.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. The <UseMaui>true</UseMaui> installs the 8.0.3 packages instead of the 8.0.6 -I can update one of the packages manually but after restarting it rolls back automatically to 8.0.3. It doesn't let you remove them or update them to the correct version.

Comment: I have not been able to remove the package in question.  I've moved on since I have a deadline in completing this code and will circle back later on this.

Comment: It could be related to Visual Studio. Try to update VS to the latest version?

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT I had just updated not long ago so didn't even think to look.  There was an update, but it appears the issue is still there.

Comment: Well, you can report it on [MAUI GitHub Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues) or [Visual Studio Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio?sort=newest).

Comment: I've got several items that are being triaged right now with Maui, it's hard to keep up with those items.  I guess I can open another.

Answer (score 4):

Case opened with MS here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Unable-to-upgrade-nuget-package-Microsof/10575432, please vote and/or comment with additional information if you are having this issue @JpSiller.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did.
I made sure first to disable MauiEssentials on the csproj.

So specify:

```
<UseMauiEssentials>false</UseMauiEssentials>
```

Then make sure to add the following nuget packages into your project file. And make sure to specify Include so Nuget restore won't rollback to 8.0.6.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.14" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="8.0.14" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Essentials" Version="8.0.14" />
```

Here I'm explicitly installing Microsoft.Maui.essentials package, and I'm not relying on the MAUI Internals to install the right version.

I hope it helps you.